# Optimizing react-to-print for all/most browsers and mobile devices

Tags: css, reactjs, react-to-print

I'm working on a sample [react-to-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print) resume template for a larger portfolio website.
I optimized this page using Chrome and Edge on a laptop, however when the print button is clicked using Firefox, the background color in the `.name-contact` class is white and the page spills over to the next page. Ideally I would like the resume template to fit onto one page like it does with Edge and Chrome.

Also for mobile browsers, the print preview is not at all like it is on a laptop. I'm trying to make the print preview uniform throughout all browsers and all devices.

I'm not sure if this is a CSS or a react-to-print issue.

I have the resume template hosted with GitHub pages:
[spencertimothy.github.io/React-to-print-example](https://spencertimothy.github.io/React-to-print-example)

Here is the CSS for the `@media print` query:

```css
 @page {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }


  button {
    display: none;
  }


  .my-resume {
    width: auto;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    color: black;
    margin: .5cm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: none;
  }

  h4,
  .education>h2,
  .projects>h2,
  .relavent-skills>h2,
  .work-experience>h2,
  b {
    color: black
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 36pt;
  }

  .name-contact {
    background-color: var(--color-light-grey);
    border-top: 5px solid var(--color-light-blue);
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  }

  .resume-icons,
  .map-icon {
    color: var(--color-button-blue);
  }

  li>b {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot from print preview with Firefox:
[Firefox laptop print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3JkS.png)

Here is a screenshot form print preview from a mobile device with Safari:
[Safari mobile device print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7ess.jpg)

Here is a screenshot from print preview from a mobile device with Firefox and DuckDuckGo:
[DuckDuckGo and Firefox mobile device print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SGBe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below to get the background styles while printing in firefox & IE. For me it is fitting into one page while printing.

```
@media print {
 .my-resume {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; /* chrome */
    color-adjust: exact; /* firefox and IE */
  } 
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN7pl.jpg